# Bootstrap tooltip (popover) behaving strangely

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I have a tooltip in a widget of my application, and despite I always do the same to initialize it, `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();`,  depending on where do I come from (F5 or from another widget).

However, in each case I have two different behaviours

### 1st case (pressing F5)

`<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle no-tc-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" data-original-title="A message"></i>`

And it does not change when hovering

### 2nd case (comming from other widget)

The icon that triggers the tooltip is:

`<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle no-tc-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="A message"></i>`

And when hovering changes to:

`<i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle no-tc-icon" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="" aria-describedby="ui-id-16"></i>`

---

The desired behaviour is the case 1, in the second I got a different tooltip style and the `placement` attribute is not honored.

Any idea why the 2nd case could be happening?

Note: I hope I can edit the title into something more meaningful once I learn what is happening.

Comment: Can you please explain when do you get the second case i.e. placement attribute is not honored

Comment: I don't know what else could I explain. In both cases I have the same html base code, but the resulting code when applying `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();` is different. In 1st case I press F5, in 2nd case I come from another widget of my application. But the html and javascript is the same in both cases.